# how to get socket.io number of clients in room?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, webrtc

**my socket.io version 1.3.5**

I want to get number of clients in particular room.

This is my code.

```
 socket.on('create or join', function (numClients, room) {
            socket.join(room);
    });
```

I use this code for get clients in room :

```
console.log('Number of clients',io.sockets.clients(room));
```

Comment: Please elaborate on what you need help with.

Comment: i want to get number of clients in a particular room

Answer (score 19):

This works for version 3

```js
io.sockets.adapter.rooms.get(roomName).size
```

Answer (score 7):

To get the number of clients in a room you can do the following:

```
    function NumClientsInRoom(namespace, room) {
      var clients = io.nsps[namespace].adapter.rooms[room];
      return Object.keys(clients).length;
    }
```

This variable clients will hold a object where each client is a key.
Then you just get the number of clients (keys) in that object.

If you haven't defined a namespace the default one is "/".

Answer (score 5):

Have a counter variable to keep count, increase when someone joins and decrease when people disconnect.

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {

var numClients = {};

socket.on('join', function (room) {
    socket.join(room);
    socket.room = room;
    if (numClients[room] == undefined) {
        numClients[room] = 1;
    } else {
        numClients[room]++;
    }
});

socket.on('disconnect', function () {
     numClients[socket.room]--;
});
```

Comment: the room name is dynamic, its come from client side.

Comment: Edited to use the room variable.

Comment: I think your code shows total number of clients in sock.io

Comment: You want to keep count for each dynamic room?

Comment: Updated: Now, you can get number of clients in each room by `numClients[socket.room]`.

Answer (score 4):

this work for me

```
io.in('yourRoom').allSockets().then(result=>{
    console.log(res.size) })
```

Answer (score 2):

This work for me.

```
// check if your room isn't undefined.
if (io.sockets.adapter.rooms['your room name']) 
{
   // result
   console.log(io.sockets.adapter.rooms['your room name'].length);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Only one that worked for me in 2022 using socket.io 4.5.1:

```
io._nsps.get('/').adapter.rooms.get('your-room-id').size;
```

Thanks to @Abhishek Kumar, just making a top level comment for visibility.

Answer (score 1):

In socket.io ^1.4.6

```
function numClientsInRoom(namespace, room) {
    var clients = io.nsps[namespace].adapter.rooms[room].sockets;
    return Object.keys(clients).length;
}
```

You need to add `.sockets` to `rooms[room]`, because variable clients holds all connection inside `sockets` variable.

Answer (score 1):

i'm a bit late to the party, but I found a **valid** solution:

> `io.in('YOUR_ROOM').engine.clientsCount;`

Answer (score 0):

socket.io's `rooms` is a `Map` whose elements map to `Set`s.

You use `get(roomId)` to get the value of that `roomId` in a `Map` and you use `.size` to the number of elements in a set unlike `.length` for number of elements in an array.

```js
socket.on("join-room",roomId => {
    const room = io.of("/yourNameSpace").adapter.rooms.get(roomId)
     if(room === undefined || room.size < 2) {
       socket.join(roomId)
     }else {
       io.of("/yourNameSpace").emit("can't join link")
     }
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
io.nsps['/'].adapter.rooms['your room name'].sockets;
```

If your namespace is not `/`, change it.

Comment: This worked for me.
var count = io._nsps.get('/').adapter.rooms.get(roomName).size;

Answer (score 0):

#### Without Adapter

If you only have one server instance, the easiest way is:

```js
// rooms is a Map object
const rooms = io.of("/").adapter.rooms;
const roomSockets = rooms.get('roomid')
```

You can see from the official document [here](https://socket.io/docs/v4/rooms/#implementation-details)

#### Using An Adapter (Redis)

But if you have multiple server instance and are using Adapters like Redis, this will not work as it will only returns the socket in that instance memory, so based on which server instance you request hit, the result will vary.

To get the actual rooms and sockets, you will need to (for RedisAdapter):

```js
// this is a Set of room ids
const rooms = await io.of("/").adapter.allRooms();
// or get the sockets directly if you know the room id
const roomSockets = await io.of("/").adapter.sockets(new Set(['room id']);
```

You can see more methods [here](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-redis-adapter#redisadapter)

Answer (score 0):

[Latest Documentation (v4)](https://socket.io/docs/v4/server-instance/#fetchsockets)

> // return all Socket instances in the "room1" room of the main namespace

> const sockets = await io.in("room1").fetchSockets();

try sockets.size or sockets.length to get the actual count