# socket.io room size 4.x

Tags: node.js, socket.io

So i've been making a realtime E2EE chatting application in node.js and socket.io, and I've ran into an issue

I'm using a recent socket.io version, specifically 4.2.0 and I've been attempting to find out the number of clients within a room, in order to create a check to either allow, or block access to a chat area, since it doesn't support more than 2 clients in 1 room.

My variables/includes for socket.io

```
var socket = require("socket.io")
var io = socket(server)


var chat = io.of('/socket').on('connection', function (socket) {
socket.on('loginchat', async function(data){
 io.in(data.id).allSockets().then(result=>{
console.log(result.size) })
});
});
```

data.id is a randomly generated string and used to create a room server side, so my idea was to use allSockets() to get a count of sockets connected to that room, but it returns zero even with 2 clients connected.
allSockets() idea from https://stackoverflow.com/a/66065685/16140221

I can't find a working solution on stack overflow, or anything inside the docs that is an obvious method to do so. I'm not the best at socket.io since I simply picked it up to use for this project, so any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var socket = require("socket.io")
var io = socket(server)

var chat = io.of('/socket').on('connection', function (socket) {
socket.on('loginchat', async function(data){
const sockets = await io.of("/socket").in(data.id).fetchSockets();
  console.log(sockets.length)
 if(sockets.length <= 1){
  socket.room = data.id;
  socket.join(data.id);
 }else{
   //attempting to join a room with greater than 2 users
   console.log("too many")
 }
});
});
```

https://socket.io/docs/v3/migrating-from-3-x-to-4-0/

Using the fetchSockets() and checking the length of the object, you are able to check the length or numbers of users in a room.

Working in Socket.io v4.3.1 but most likely functioning in any v4.x

Answer (score 1):

Given the example you provided, you don't seem to ever make a socket to join a room. So your room is forever empty.

According [the socket.io documentation](https://socket.io/docs/v4/rooms/) you must first listen for the `connection` event, then you must use `join` to add users to the room.

```js
const socket = require("socket.io")
const io = socket(server)

io.on("connection", socket => {

  socket.on('loginchat', async data => {
     //Assuming data.id is the room identifier
     const roomUsers = await io.in(data.id).allSockets();
     
     //There, you make your socket join the room if room users are not exceeding 
     //your maximum
     if(roomUsers.size < 2) socket.join(data.id);
  });
  
});
```

Comment: Hi thanks for replying, sorry for not making it clearer but I did put that code within the connection event, that part was just for that event, and I did have the socket.join, I forgot to include it in the code block, That's my fault. I attempted to use your example, however it returned 0 even after a client joined the room

Comment: The socket docs are still not clear on a solution for this, I've seen examples for version 3.x, but I cannot find one for 4.x, is my only solution to downgrade?

Comment: You can either downgrade or open an issue on socket.io repository, since it's either the doc is not up to date, or a bug to report.

Comment: don't worry! It's not really an issue in the docs, more a non clear way to do so, however I answered the question myself once I found the solution and marked it as correct, so other users could see it.

Comment: this was the best option because it identifies all users from a selected room. Its way better than using "sockets.length" or io.of("/socket").in(data.id).fetchSockets();